# Not able to play a radio stream(shoutcast) continuously in WP8.1 - C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, shoutcast

In windows 10 shoutcast stream is working fine.

What we are trying to do is continuously fetch chunks of data from the url and fetch to background player. And we are able to play for a few seconds and the player stops.

This is what we had tried:

```
try {
    bool initialRq = false;
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri(RadioUrl));

    // Do not buffer the response.
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendRequestAsync(request,
        HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).AsTask(cts.Token);

    //string text = Helpers.SerializeHeaders(response);

    IOutputStream output = bufferStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0);
    StringBuilder responseBody = new StringBuilder();
    using(Stream responseStream = (await response.Content.ReadAsInputStreamAsync()).AsStreamForRead()) {
        int read = 0;

        byte[] responseBytes = new byte[1024 * 20];
        byte[] strippedResponseBytes = new byte[1024 * 20];

        bool headerIsDone = false;
        do {
            StreamReader headerReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            int icyHeaderLength = 0;
            while (!headerIsDone) {
                string headerLine = headerReader.ReadLine();
                icyHeaderLength += headerLine.Length;

                if (headerLine.StartsWith("icy-name:")) {
                    StationName = headerLine.Substring(9);
                    icyHeaderLength += headerLine.Length;
                } else if (headerLine.StartsWith("icy-genre:")) {
                    Genre = headerLine.Substring(10);
                    icyHeaderLength += headerLine.Length;
                } else if (headerLine.StartsWith("icy-br:")) {
                    BitRate1 = short.Parse(headerLine.Substring(7));
                    icyHeaderLength += headerLine.Length;
                } else if (headerLine.StartsWith("icy-metaint:")) {
                    MetaInt = int.Parse(headerLine.Substring(12));
                    MetadataAvailable = true;
                    icyHeaderLength += headerLine.Length;
                } else if (headerLine.Equals("")) {
                    headerIsDone = true;
                    icyHeaderLength += headerLine.Length;
                    SamplingRate = samplingRateTable[0, 1];
                }
            }

            read = await responseStream.ReadAsync(responseBytes, icyHeaderLength, responseBytes.Length - icyHeaderLength);
            strippedResponseBytes = new byte[responseBytes.Length - icyHeaderLength];
            if (icyHeaderLength > 0) {
                strippedResponseBytes = responseBytes.ToList().GetRange(icyHeaderLength, responseBytes.Length - icyHeaderLength).ToArray();
            } else {
                strippedResponseBytes = responseBytes;
            }

            await CopyChunk(output, strippedResponseBytes); //Method for continuosly filling the bufferStream
            if (bufferStream.Size >= 1024 * 20 && !initialRq) {
                mediaPlayer.SetStreamSource(bufferStream);
                initialRq = true;
            }
        } while (read != 0);
    }
    string responseText = responseBody.ToString();
} catch (TaskCanceledException) {

}
```

Here we are receiving data stream from  the radio url and stripping the ICY headers from the data stream and fetching that streams to background player. A bufferStream is used for continuously filling the data stream. Currently I am setting the source, after the bufferStream is filled to 20kb. If I am increasing that size I am able to hear the music for more time.But not able to listen continuously. What I am doing wrong?

Please help. Thanks in advance.